# Bootstrap 4 rows and columns properties are not behaving properly in Safari, the fixes for row::before , ::after also don't seems to work for me

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, safari, cross-browser

Too much trouble in cross-browser testing for Safari since bootstrap 4 has added additional properties for rows the grid format is showing disturbed. i want to show them exactly as in Chrome or Firefox. i have tried all the existing fixes related to this issue but some how it doesn't seems to work for me.

.row::after, .row::before

```
    display: inline-block!important;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
```

Following are the properties of Bootstrap 4 which are not supported in Safari

.row

```
    display: -ms-flexbox; //not supported in Safari
    display: flex;        //not supported in Safari
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;  //not supported in Safari
    flex-wrap: wrap;      //not supported in Safari
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
```

.col-6

```
   -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;     //not supported in Safari
   flex: 0 0 50%;         //not supported in Safari
   max-width: 50%;        //not supported in Safari
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `::before` and `::after` on the row to `display:none;` as follows:

```
.row:before, .row:after { display: none !important; }
```

Comment: no .... still the same problem .... i think the problem is with the version of Safari available for windows i.e v5.1 introduced in 2015. what do you think ?